# tkinter page layout with labelframes

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Thank you for patience but to my earlier question the one part i have figured it out..
i have a frame (PageTwo) it has a 2 labelframes sidePan and mainPan i want to add a third lowerPan that will be below the mainPan as image below show [image]

the code for the entire frame(pageTwo) is below

````
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Frame.pack(self,side=TOP, fill='x')
        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page",command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack(side=LEFT)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go to page two", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne)).pack(side=LEFT)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go to page three", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageThree)).pack(side=LEFT)
        tk.Button(self, text="page 2", command=lambda: master.destroy).pack(side=RIGHT)
                
        
        sidePan = LabelFrame(text='sidepan')
        
        sidePan.pack(side=LEFT ,anchor=NW)

        sidePan.label = tk.Label(sidePan, text="Main Page1")
        sidePan.label.pack(padx=100,pady=10)
        sidePan.label = tk.Label(sidePan, text="Main Page2")
        sidePan.label.pack(padx=0,pady=10)
        sidePan.label = tk.Label(sidePan, text="Main Page3")
        sidePan.label.pack(padx=0,pady=10)
        sidePan.label = tk.Label(sidePan, text="Main Page4")
        sidePan.label.pack(padx=0,pady=10)
        
        mainPan = LabelFrame(text='mainPan')
        mainPan.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=NW,  fill='x', expand=YES,ipadx=10,ipady=0)
        
        #LabelFrameStops=LabelFrame(frame2,text='ChildFrame',padx=0,pady=0,width=100,height=100).pack(side=LEFT)
        LabelFrameStops=LabelFrame(mainPan,text='inner',width=100,height=100)
        LabelFrameStops.pack(side=LEFT,padx=0,pady=0)
        Label(LabelFrameStops,text='Design Time \nActual Time \nWaste Time\nSim Time',width=15,height=5,anchor=W).pack()
        Button(LabelFrameStops, text="Analysis").pack()
        mainPan.separator = Frame(mainPan,width=50,height=2, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
        mainPan.separator.pack(side=LEFT,fill=NONE, padx=5, pady=5)

        LabelFrameStops=LabelFrame(mainPan,text='inner',width=100,height=100)
        LabelFrameStops.pack(side=LEFT,padx=0,pady=0)
        Label(LabelFrameStops,text='Design Time : 1000',anchor=W).pack()
        Label(LabelFrameStops,text='Actual Time:0000',anchor=W).pack()
        Label(LabelFrameStops,text='Waste Time:0000',anchor=W).pack()
        Label(LabelFrameStops,text='Sim Time:0000',anchor=W).pack()
        Button(LabelFrameStops, text="hhh").pack()```
````

Comment: Can you please provide a question? I would like to provide a answer but I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Also your code can't be run and has many syntax errors. Solve them and then post your edited code.

Comment: ok will do thanx

Comment: There are still syntax errors. Please provide minimal reproducible code so I can execute it on my machine and help you out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228795/discussion-between-farai-huruba-and-jakub-szlaur).

Comment: I think the errors are because OP hasn't specified their imports, from what I can see, they are using `tk` as an alias for `tkinter`, using `tkinter` variables directly and using all the widgets except `Labelframe` directly as well (from the parameters). So I am assuming the order of import would be `import tkinter as tk` `from tkinter.ttk import *` `from tkinter import *`